# AWS EC2 Instances. How to keep tag columns view same?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I view AWS instances I can select specific Tag columns in the preferences. The website used to remember these settings and I would see my tags everyday. Now every few hours the tags disappear and I have to add them manually in the preferences.

Is there a way to save the tags you want to display? I tried both the old display and the "New EC2 Experience" and the results is the same.

Comment: I don't have a solution but know that you are not alone, I have been facing the same issue.

Comment: My solution was basically to remove any built-in Browser blockers from AWS. For example, I use Brave, and I removed all the shields from AWS. That helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Brave browser which is pretty aggresive at blocking the websites. After I removed all the "shields" from AWS websites I was able to save the tags.